# Sharing parent property value with all derived children

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Say there is a parent class Shape and a child class Rectangle.  I want to reuse a parent class property's value from within the child class.

Can I do this without re-initializing it in the child class (using call or apply)?

I want all the child objects to use the same parent property value.

```js
//Parent
function Shape(ctx) {
  this.context = ctx;
}
Shape.prototype.getContext = function() { return this.context; };

//Child - rectangle inherits from shape
function Rectangle(x,y,w,h) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
}
//setup inheritance
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
  //want to use inherited context here
  return this.context;
}

//create and run
var shape = new Shape("value");
var rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);

//returns "value"
console.log( shape.getContext() );
//returns undefined - needing "value"
console.log( rectangle.draw() );
```

EDIT - After the responses below I think this is what I need.  Since the rectangle instance is not inheriting from the shape instance the "value" assigned to shape is not being passed to rectangle.  How about assigning it as the default inside Shape and then calling the Shape constructor inside the Rectangle constructor.  This allows me to share the same context value to all the child objects right?

Side issue, the setter doesn't affect Shape children.  So I'm working on that.

```js
//Parent
function Shape() {
  this.context = "value";
}
Shape.prototype.getContext = function() { return this.context; };
Shape.prototype.setContext = function(x) { this.context = x; };

//Child - rectangle inherits from shape
function Rectangle(x,y,w,h) {
  Shape.call(this);
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
}
//setup inheritance
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
  //want to use inherited context here
  return this.context;
}

//create and run
var rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
//returns "value"
console.log( rectangle.draw() );
```

EDIT - Thanks to the responses, I think below is accomplishing what I was initially trying to do.  The Shape parent begins with a default context value.  The Shape constructor now also accepts an argument in case child classes want to change it when initially called.  Each child class then has a getter and setter as well for the context, but it will always default to the initial Parent value unless changed.  After looking into it more the Shape is starting to feel like an abstract class or an interface, but that has nothing to do with what I was initially asking.

```
//Parent
function Shape(ctx) {
  this.context = (typeof ctx === "undefined") ? "default" : ctx;
}
Shape.prototype.getContext = function() { return this.context; };
Shape.prototype.setContext = function(x) { this.context = x; };

//Child - rectangle inherits from shape
function Rectangle(x,y,w,h) {
  //calls parent constructor
  Shape.call(this);
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
}
//setup inheritance
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
//getter and setter - context defaults to parent value, but can be changed
Rectangle.prototype.getContext = function() { return this.context; };
Rectangle.prototype.setContext = function(x) { this.context = x; };
//other rectangle methods
Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
  return "doing something with " + this.context;
}

//create and run
var rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
//starts with Parent "default"
console.log( rectangle.getContext() );
//changes and uses different context
rectangle.setContext("different context");
console.log( rectangle.draw() );
```

Comment: Your `rectangle` instance is not derived from that `shape` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I do this without re-initializing it in the child class (using call or apply)?

No, there's no way around calling your super constructor.

Notice that this is not *re*-initialising the property, the call is creating and initialising the property *at all*.

> I want to reuse a parent class property's value from within the child class.

This doesn't really make sense. The property is part of the instance, not of the class. There is no instance of the parent class if you have multiple children, there are just child instances. If you are really creating an instance of the parent class (like in your example code), then that is  a separate object and has nothing to do with the other instances - mostly, the children objects are not in any way derived from that parent instance.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I've edited the code above.  Now I'm trying to find a way to make the parent setter apply to all child objects...

Comment: Yes, the updated code appears to work fine, giving each object a property with the same value. However, I don't understand what you mean by "*make the parent setter apply to all child objects*"? A setter always only is invoked on a single instance. It sounds like `context` should not be a property of your `Rectangle`s at all, but rather a global - maybe a static property or an attribute of a dedicated `DrawingArea` class?

Comment: you're right I just messed on the setter, from your comment I added a getter and setter to the child prototype where it should be changed if needed (i.e. on the instance, but for all other children it would default to the Parent value).

Comment: your indication to call the super class helped me to get the default value and the other comments helped, so thanks and I'll select you as the answer

Answer (score 0):

The return value is `undefined` when you do this to setup your rectangle:

```
//create and run
var shape = new Shape("value");
var rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
```

because you are actually *not* connecting that `shape` to `rectangle`. You have merely made two separate instances of Shape and Rectangle which aside from sharing certain structures have nothing to do with each other.

There are possible scenarios to fixing this. Create a new Shape to seed the value with up front when defining the prototype.

```
//Use predefined Shape
var shape = new Shape("value");
Rectangle.prototype = shape;
```

Now when the previously shown call to `draw` is used, `value` will be returned and logged to the console.

This is not a complete scenario in my opinion though because while you have defined a getter for the context, there may be scenarios where you wish to change that. I would also suggest implementing a setter for the context so that you can inject different ones if you feel like it.

Comment: "*you can only get there through exposed methods in the prototype chain*" - how so? What's wrong with `this.context`?

Comment: Thanks @TravisJ I took your comments and made edits to the question.  I'm trying to get the parent value to be shared across the child objects, so I think the edits above handle it, however now adding a setter like you mentioned seems to be a problem (changing the parent value does not affect the children).

Comment: @ShawnMoore - Changing the parent value as you show will only affect the children of that instance. You need to hold on to an instance of the parent in order to make changes to that so that all the derived instances still reference only one parent instance. Either that, or have it be in a variable outside of this setup.

Comment: @TravisJ After reviewing it some more it would be a bad idea to have all the child objects be affected by a change to the parent.  I'll keep the Parent value defaulted and the children begin with it unless it is intentionally set to something else.